# Setting an expiration date with javaScript is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, date, cookies, addeventlistener

```
  const cookieButton = document.getElementById('store-cookie')

  cookieButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const input = document.getElementById('fav-cookie').value
    let date = new Date()
    let minutes = 30;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000))
    document.cookie = `favCookie=${input}; expires=${date.toTimeString()};`
  })
```

I'm working on a coding problem meant to be only used in javaScript. It requires to make a cookie with the value of an input field (on a linked html), on pressing a button. The bonus for this question requires the cookie to expire after 30 minutes it's created. Currently, this code is just saving the
`favCookie=input;`
but it is not adding an expiration date. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can add minutes more semantically as `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 30)`. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `toUTCString()` instead.

```js
 const cookieButton = document.getElementById('store-cookie');
 cookieButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const input = document.getElementById('fav-cookie').value;
    const date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30* 60 * 1000));
   document.cookie = `favCookie=${input}; expires=${date.toUTCString()};`;
 });
```

Cookies are always tricky. I believe it is because your timestamp should be formatted like so:

`2021-10-23T20:32:38.000Z`

Instead you currently have set by `toTimeString()`

`22:29:12 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`

Comment: Wow yep this is exactly it. Everything checks out now I just need to remember the correct formatting!

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 date variables, on the second use the setMinutes method to add 30mins to the current time then create a function to clear/change the value if and when the current date/time equals the new date.

```
 var expire = new Date();
 expire.setMinutes( expire.getMinutes() + 30 );
```

Comment: `setMinutes` states in the docs for the first argument: "minutesValue – An integer between 0 and 59 representing the minutes."
What happens if you run this at 12:45? Wouldn't it call setMinutes with 75 (45+30)?
EDIT: It appears internally this is handled as expected, despite what the docs say.